# How to get emoji completion in markdown with `:<emoji>`, using neovim and coc

Tags: neovim, font, plugin-coc

I'm sure that I've seen it so that one is able to use `:<emoji` and there's a pop up menu to select from, I can't seem to get this working though.

I tried installing: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-emoji , but it isn't working as I'd like, [and I'm not sure that it will](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-emoji/issues/29#issuecomment-610755801).

Answer (score 5):

One way to get this feature is by using [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and [coc-emoji](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coc-emoji).

Coc is a plugin which allows you to get the same Language Server Protocol (autocompletion, linting, go to definition, etc...) as VSCode because it uses the same extensions as VSCode. This is a pretty powerful tool but installing it just to get emoji support might be a bit overkill.

However if you do use coc you can use `:CocInstall coc-emoji` to get the emoji completion source, by default it is enabled only for the `markdown` file type. And then inserting `:` and the first letters of the emoji name gives you something like this:

[image]

To make it available on other filetypes you can use `:CocConfig` to edit `"coc.source.emoji.filetypes"`.

Comment: @baxx Please let me know if the answer doesn't solve your issue, otherwise don't hesitate to mark it as accepted to let future readers know that it's a solution they can use too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/FuDesign2008/emoji-snippets.vim, which is working with YouCompleteMe

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The best answers include explanations with links, which sometimes die.